# What does "assigns" do in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, rspec

I am currently attempt to learn Ruby on Rails, and the testing framework RSpec. What does `assigns` do in this RSpec test?

```
 describe "GET index" do
    it "assigns all mymodel as @mymodel" do
      mymodel = Factory(:mymodel)
      get :index
      assigns(:mymodels).should eq([mymodel])
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`assigns` simply checks the value of the instance variables you set in your controller.

Here it checks `@mymodels`.

Comment: Yup. And therefore you can ignore it, because you shouldn't be writing controller specs. Use Cucumber for your controllers, RSpec only for your models.

Comment: @MarnenLaibow-Koser: cucumber is made for integration specs. Testing controllers is functional testing. Both are necessary and don't have the same purpose.

Comment: Functional testing of controllers is completely unnecessary in 99% of cases. It tests the wrong things -- that is, it tests implementation, not behavior -- and so is a waste of time and effort; worse, it can mislead you into thinking your application is well tested when it's not. Generally speaking, it should not be done.